# What is the best way to use findAll with Pageable in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have employee class

```
@Entity
 class Employee {
     @Id
     Integer id;
     String name;
     Integer age;
}
```

and another class EmployeeInfo:

```
class EmployeeInfo {
         
     Integer id;
     String name;
 }
```

Now, I need to build a service to get a paginated list of EmployeeInfo by using `findAll(Pageable pageable)`
from the repository

```
 @Repository
    public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
```

what is the best way to do that? I want to avoid getting the page from findAll and create a new object of EmployeeInfo then adding it to a list in a loop

Comment: Why don't you try [JPA Projection](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize spring-data-jpa **projections**.
There are many ways to use them (open/closed projections, class or interface based, etc.), but since you already have a `EmployeeInfo` class, it can be achieved by defining a new method in your repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    Page<EmployeeInfo> getAllBy(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Note that your projection DTO class properties must exactly match properties in the aggregate root (entity class).
Also reference documentation suggest to define `.equals()` and `.hashcode()` methods.

Other methods can be found in the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).